# How to switch from global to local scope in python?

Tags: python, function, scope, global, local

```
value = 4

def test():
    global value
    print(value + 2)

    value = -10
    print(value+5)

test()
print(value)
```

I know it is not a good idea to shadow variables; however, I am attempting this just so I can understand the concept. In the above code, is there a way to switch back to the local scope so that `value = -10` only changes `value` to `-10` within the function?

Answer (score 5):

```
value = 4

def test():
    print(globals()['value'] + 2)

    value = -10
    print(value+5)

test()
```

prints

```
6
-5
```

There is no way to "switch" between global `value` and local `value` once `global value` has been declared, but you can let `value` be a local variable within `test` and access the global value through the `globals()` dict.

Comment: if i call `print(value)` it prints `-10`

Comment: Yes, that's as it should be, if you are calling `print(value)` in `test`. If you want the global value, use `globals()['value']`.